# Android 5.1.1: adding photo from the gallery using setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT) is always null

Tags: android

When I am adding photos from the directory using

```
Intent addPictureIntent = new Intent();
                addPictureIntent.setType("image/*");
                addPictureIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); this always returns  this  acontent://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3D91 which is null.
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I am getting a null return". You may also wish to consider expanding your question to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem, as what you have here is apparently incomplete.

Comment: show your Manifext.xml file code. Have you added this permission ? 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Yes, I had. here's my part of my manifest.xml.  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /